# How to redefine itemize for Beamer moderntimeline slide

Tags: beamer, itemize, moderntimeline

I am preparing a slide for my PhD defense with a list of research stays with some tasks and publications. My question is how to modify the itemize environment to act like in a article template so that the items appear with - and they are squeezed as much as possible to save space.

More over how those environment definitions work? Because when integrating this slide with the entire presentation, all the format of the modertimeline gets random and the slide destroied.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[firstyear=2009,lastyear=2014]{moderntimeline}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\makeatletter
% change these colors according to your needs
\colorlet{color0}{blue}
\colorlet{color1}{olive}

\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{a~}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries\raggedright #3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, \raggedright{\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{,  \raggedright#5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, \raggedright#6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small\raggedright#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} & {#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\tlmaxdates{2009}{2014}
\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr0.9\linewidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax}

\tikzset{
    tl@startyear/.append style={
        xshift=(0.5-\tl@startfraction)*\hintscolumnwidth,
        anchor=base
    }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2001},
    Journal = {Some Conference},
    title = {First Article Title Apha AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAA AA AA AA A AAA A A A AAAA}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage     [   style=numeric-comp,
                            autocite=superscript, % apply options here.
                            sortcites,
                            backend=bibtex
                        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{scalefnt,lmodern}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tldatelabelcventry{2009.580}{June 2009}{MSc Thesis}{}{}
{}{}{}

\tllabelcventry{2009.583}{2009.833}{July-Sept. 2009}{Research stay}{Some Lab at SomeUniversity}
{Somewhere}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item task 1
\item task 2
\item More awesome tasks we developed
\end{itemize}
}

\tllabelcventry{2011.500}{2011.995}{June-Dec. 2011}{Research stay}{Some Lab at SomeUniversity}{Seomewhere}{}{}

\tldatelabelcventry{2010.500}{June 2010}{Some Conf. 2010}{}{}
{}{{\scriptsize \fullcite{A01}}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\begin{itemize}\setlength\itemsep{-5pt}`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Surely, your code is not *minimal*.

Comment: @KevinC, yes this is like doing it manually. I can reduce the interspace, add \vspace{-10pt} to eliminate the extra space and use item[--] to change the bullet.

Comment: @Jubobs yes, you are right. Now that I look it back plus the answer, its not minimal at all.